# How do I add code when replying to questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown, editor, source-code

I know the answers for many questions but I can't reply because I don't know where to paste the code.

Comment: Just put it in with your question. If you want to paste more than a couple of dozen lines, then whittle it down to just the core. No (sane) person will debug huge swathes of code for you.

Comment: wow, seriously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The small **"{}" image** on the toolbar above the textbox can handle code implementation.

[image]

Comment: @LGSon - it wasn't useful because you could have made the edit yourself rather than flagging it for someone else to do. I pointed this out in the reason I gave for declining the flag.

Comment: That I could have done .. will do that next time

Answer (score 3):

Paste your code, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to format it as code, or press the small "{}" button on the edit bar.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Or just **indent** everything four spaces.